# Detect window onscroll in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating an APP in React Typescript. I am trying to avoid using Jquery where possible.

I need to detect when the window has scrolled to a point so I can update the header class. This is how it would be done in Jquery:

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll >= 200) {
      $(".navbar-default").addClass("dark");
    } else {
      $(".navbar-default").removeClass("dark");
    }
  });
```

My entry point HTML looks like this (cut down)

```
<body>
<noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<body>
```

the entry tsx file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Layout from './views/layout/layout';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { enthusiasm } from './reducers/index';
import { StoreState } from './types/index';

const store = createStore<StoreState>(enthusiasm, {
  enthusiasmLevel: 1,
  languageName: 'TypeScript',
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Layout />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

What would be the recommended way to replicate this type of event?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/shotaK/redux-lazy-scroll/blob/master/ReduxLazyScroll.js ; it is the component with the exact same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to update the state, not the dom elements. If you are adding new liisteners on componentDidMount, you have to also remove listeners on componentWillUnmount.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},

handleScroll: function(event) {
 //your code to handle scroll
},
```

Comment: I was considering doing it this way. Would you put this code just at the bottom of the inital HTML page in a script file? So not within any REACT Typescript code?

Comment: @michael I edited the code and this is more react way to do it. If you can use external stuff then you can also check [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) directive. It's easy to use and quite good.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and we solved it by building a component with a child function, like so

```
export interface ScrollElementProps {
  children?: (isInRange) => any
  throttle?: number
  maxScroll?: number
  minScroll?: number
}

export interface ScrollElementState {
  isInRange: boolean
}

export default
class ScrollElement extends React.Component<ScrollElementProps, ScrollElementState> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<ScrollElementProps> = {
    throttle: 200,
    minScroll: 0,
    maxScroll: Number.MAX_VALUE
  };

  state: ScrollElementState = {
    isInRange: false
  };

  private listenToScroll =
      _.throttle(this.props.throttle, () => this.scrollListener());

  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenToScroll();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.listenToScroll);
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children(this.state.isInRange);
  }

  private scrollListener() {
    this.setState({ isInRange: this.isWithinScrollRange() });
  }

  private isWithinScrollRange() {
    const { minScroll, maxScroll } = this.props;
    return _.inRange(minScroll, maxScroll, documentScrollTop());
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
<ScrollElement maxScroll={200}>
{isInRange => (
    <NavBar className={isInRange ? 'dark' : ''}/>
)}
</ScrollElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small React/Typescript solution that does what you want.

Typescript:

```
  interface AppState {
    scroller: number;
  }

  class Application extends React.Component<{}, AppState> {

    state = { scroller: 0 };

    handleScroll = () => {
      this.setState({ scroller: document.documentElement.scrollTop });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <nav className={this.state.scroller > 200 ? 'dark' : 'normal'}>This is the nav bar (scroller: {this.state.scroller})</nav>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  /*
   * Render the above component into the div#app
   */
  React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="root"></app>
```

CSS (Sass):

```
body
  padding: 3rem
  background: #333
  display: flex
  font-family: Helvetica Neue

nav
  font-size: 2em
  display: inline-block
  position: fixed
  top: 0
  padding: 1rem

nav.dark
  background-color: black
  color: white

nav.normal
  background-color: lightgrey
  color: black

p
  margin-top: 1em
  color: #aaa
  width: 300px
```

Try it on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMQRqV

Note how the color of the "nav" element changes when you scroll beyond 200.

Hope this helps!